# #java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester` error and I am stuck with this error for more than a month. I have tried all Digester versions available and I  also checked for duplicate JARs in classpath.

I have  designed the report through `iReport-5.6.0` and I used the JARs from the 
`iReport-5.6.0\ireport\modules\ext` and other required JARs.

Error-Log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:108)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.examples.JasperMongoDBConnection.main(JasperMongoDBConnection.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: do you have http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/ in your classpath ?

Comment: I had the same issue, what all i did is included the `commons-digester` jar in my class path.

Comment: @FredericClose - yes I have Digester in my classpath . I have version 2.1 in my classpath

Comment: @Salah- Yes I have added the same , but not sure as why i am getting the same issue , will there be any issue in eclispe as I am running through Eclipse

Comment: you could add the hotspot flag -XX:+TraceClassLoading to see from which jar each class is loaded when running your code. If you see that the class has been loaded from a non expected location, that might be the issue.

Comment: @mschenk74- Thanks a lot!! I found the real issue after using the jvm TraceClassLoading . It was because it was referring to Jre/lib/ext/jasperreports-0.6.6.jar , instead of jasperreports-5.6.0 .  I deleted the file and now its working fine . I was stuck with this for very long time ..

Comment: @skaffman
For all googling this I was only able to fix with exactly digester2.1 pulled from Maven fwiw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown you should check that needed jars are properly loaded in the classpath, or maybe you are mixing versions and class names may be different (or it's behavior).
Check if the Digester jar you are adding is the one that is needed.

Check if these jar are correctly loaded:

```
jasperreports-.jar;
jasperreports-javaflow.jar;
commons-beanutils.jar;
commons-collections.jar;
commons-logging.jar;
commons-digester.jar
```

Take a look on jasper report plugin folder under your eclipse instance. Search for the commons digester jar inside this folder and copy the same jar (and the other of listed jars) in your project.

Comment: Yes , I am loading 2.1 version jar , I tried printing the classpath and it has the Digester jar 2.1 in it.

Comment: where are you running this? if it's under some server, have you checked the lib directory?

Comment: I am running locally in Eclipse

Comment: I tried by refering MAVEN repository and still I am facing same error . Any Idea on this .

Comment: @exoddus- Thanks . It was coz of jasperreports jar which was referred in different path . When I tried printing classpath , it showed exact path as I had added in build path but while on execution it was referring to  Jre/lib/ext/jasperreport jar . After removing that its fine .

Comment: @sharathYogananda, if you are trying to access the Maven repository by http, change it to https